# "Invalid syntax" from re.findall(([0-9]+\s, mystring)

Tags: python

My assignment is to use re.findall() to go through a file and add all the numbers in it together. Taking a list of strings, turning it into integers, and adding those numbers together I've already figured out how to do; the problem is getting the numbers from the text files into the list. The latest error message I got was "invalid syntax", which doesn't help me figure out why there's an error.

Code so far is as follows:

```
import re

num = [ ]

file = open('Python week 11 assignment.txt', 'rt')

num = re.findall(([0-9]+)\s,file.read())
```

Error message:

```
File "main.py", line 4

num = re.findall(([0-9]+)\s,file.read())

                        ^

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Where are the quotes?

Comment: A regex isn't necessarily valid Python code; you need a *string*.

Comment: Making regular expressions have their own literal syntax is one of Perl's worst decisions (err, no; make that "one of Perl's many bad decisions"). Whereas Ruby had the bad judgment to pick it up, I'm very much gratified that Python resisted the temptation.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just pass anything into a function, here you need the string datatype, therefore it should be:

```
 re.findall(r"([0-9]+)\s",file.read())
```

The r flag is used to pass the backslash as is for the regex and not how python would put it in a string.